Two 12v batteries and charge controller
I apologize if this seems stupid, but i have never done anything like this before. So I have two 12v batteries (car batteries) and one charge controller - the controller says PWM battery charging, and has LCD, 12v/24v 36/48v checked. I’m not sure if I’m suppose to set the controller as 12v or 24v…? I only have one 50w solar panel hooked to it but plan on hooking up one more that’s also 50w. I appreciate any assistance!

Please ask an electrical engineering design question.  Provide a block diagram and supply model numbers

If the batteries are connected in parallel (positive to positive and negative to negative), you have a 12 volt system, and the charger should be set to 12 volts.
If the batteries are connected in series (positive of one to negative of the other, and your load connected to the free positive and negative terminals), you have a 24 volt system and the charger should be set to 24 volts.

Thank you very much! A lot of this is so confusing…
